# Nginx Config file need to be configure

Tags: nginx, ssl-certificate, openssl, ocsp

I have generated the certificates as given below:

```
Root-CA  ->  Intermediate-CA  ->  Server

Root-CA:
rootca.key
rootca.crt
rootca.crl

Intermediate-CA:
intermediateca.key
intermediateca.crt
intermediateca.crl

Server:
server.key
server.crt
```

Here, `Root-CA` Signed by `Root-CA` which is Self-Signed Certificate.

Then, `Intermediate-CA` Signed by `Root-CA` and `Server` Signed by `Intermediate-CA`

All the above files are in `confs` folder

Nginx conf:

```
server {
        listen 443 ssl;
        listen [::]:443 SSL;
        server_name www.example.com;

        ssl_certificate  /home/user/confs/?;
        ssl_certificate_key /home/user/confs/?;

        ssl_ocsp on;
        ssl_verify_client on;
        ssl_verify_depth 2;
        ssl_client_certificate /home/user/confs/?;
        ssl_crl /home/user/confs/?;

        ssl_stapling on;
        ssl_stapling_verify on;
        ssl_trusted_certificate /home/user/confs/?;
}
```

What files are will be in `?`.
Can anyone please help me with the Nginx configuration.
Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
server {
        listen 443 ssl;
        listen [::]:443 SSL;
        server_name www.example.com;

        ssl_certificate  /home/user/confs/server_chain.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /home/user/confs/server.key;

        ssl_ocsp on;
        ssl_verify_client on;
        ssl_verify_depth 2;
        ssl_client_certificate /home/user/confs/rootca.crt;
        ssl_crl /home/user/confs/intermediateca.crl;

        ssl_stapling on;
        ssl_stapling_verify on;
        ssl_trusted_certificate /home/user/confs/rootca.crt;
}
```

Where `server_chain.pem` is a concatenation of `server.crt` and `intermediateca.crt` (server at the top of the file).

`ssl_client_certificate` and `ssl_trusted_certificate` are mutually exclusive. More info [here](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_ssl_module.html#ssl_client_certificate).

`ssl_crl` is pointing to your `intermediateca.crl` on the assumption that this Intermediate CA is issuing the client certificates.

Comment: Sorry ```server.crl``` is a mistake. Question is updated by removing ```server.crl```

Comment: I have configure Nginx.conf as your suggestion but I am getting an error ```400 Bad Request No required SSL certificate was sent```

Comment: You have the server set to expect a client certificate (`ssl_verify_client on`).  Did your client send a certificate?  Please see my comment on `ssl_crl` above - the answer _assumed_ that your Intermediate CA generated this client certificate.  However, your list of generated certificate doesn't include one.

Comment: These are Self-Signed Certificates. Question is updated. Is client certificate is the `server.crt`?

Comment: The Root CA is self-signed - the others are not.  The client certificate is, as the name suggests, the certificate which the client sends to the server as part of _mutual_ authentication.  The `400` error message you received was because your client didn't send the expected client certificate.  You either need to give the client a certificate whose Root CA is in `ssl_client_certificate` or you need to disable mutual authentication.

Comment: This sounds like a different question to me - it has nothing to do with Nginx.  Maybe you should accept the answer to this question and ask another about revoked certificates?

Comment: I am getting errors, not solved yet.

Comment: With `ssl_verify_client on;`, I am getting an error `400 Bad Request No required SSL certificate was sent`. Without `ssl_verify_client on;`, I can access to the web server. How to create a client certificate? What is `ssl_verify_depth 2;`?

Comment: Do you need a client certificate?  If not, there's no need to create one!